# how can i change the checkbox to disabled after the user has submit his option?

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I want to make a cinema seats buying system and I don't have a sever to run this project.

I want to try to use another document (for example:MS access database) to collect the results.

How can I disable the checkbox after the user has submit his option?
Here is my checkbox form:

```
<form>  
<ol class="seats" type="A">
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1A" />
      <label for="1A">1A</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1B" />
      <label for="1B">1B</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1C" />
      <label for="1C">1C</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1D" />
      <label for="1D">1D</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox"  disabled id="1E" />
      <label for="1E">Occupied</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1F" />
      <label for="1F">1F</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1G" />
      <label for="1G">1G</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1H" />
      <label for="1H">1H</label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</form>
```

Comment: Please precise more "choose": When changing/focusing/unfocusing the cb? ..or when submitting the form? ..accordingly you would introduce a "onXXX" parameter on every `<input/>` element or a "onSubmit" parameter on the `<form/>` element, which would in turn call a *js function*, which in turn would ensure the desired behavior (deactivation of the according `<input/>`)...

Answer (score 2):

> How can I change the checkbox to disabled after the user choose the
>   checkbox?

You can do something basic like:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="this.disabled = true"/>
```

But then I wonder how users will uncheck a checkbox if missclicked - maybe have a reset button :)

```js
function reset() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
      checkboxes[i].disabled = false;
      checkboxes[i].checked = false;
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', reset);
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="button" id="reset">Reset Selection</button>
  <ol class="seats" type="A">
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1A" onclick="this.disabled = true" />
      <label for="1A">This will be disabled after click</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1B" />
      <label for="1B">1B</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1C" />
      <label for="1C">1C</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1D" />
      <label for="1D">1D</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" disabled id="1E" />
      <label for="1E">Occupied</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1F" />
      <label for="1F">1F</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1G" />
      <label for="1G">1G</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1H" />
      <label for="1H">1H</label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</form>
```

Comment: thank for your help, but can the `disabled` change after user has submit his option

Comment: I think what you are asking is to implement the occupied functionality. If that is true then when user submits the form you need to save the values in some kind of database and when showing the view to the next user disable those seats that are occupied. You will need some kind of server side technology for that

Answer (score 0):

You could loop thru all checkboxes and add an eventlistener (in your case for `change`). Not on fireing the event you disable the checkbox.

Here is a very simple solution:

Keep in mind this will not work in old browsers. If you need support for older browsers as well, use a regular loop (eg. `for`) and use regular functions instead of `arrow function`s.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]'), x => {
  x.addEventListener('change', () => {
    x.disabled = true;
  });
})
```

```html
<form>  
  <ol class="seats" type="A">
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1A" />
      <label for="1A">1A</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1B" />
      <label for="1B">1B</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1C" />
      <label for="1C">1C</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1D" />
      <label for="1D">1D</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox"  disabled id="1E" />
      <label for="1E">Occupied</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1F" />
      <label for="1F">1F</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1G" />
      <label for="1G">1G</label>
    </li>
    <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1H" />
      <label for="1H">1H</label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</form>
```

Example for old browsers *(untestet but should work)*:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');
for(var i = checkboxes.length; i--;) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
        checkboxes[i].disabled = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: thank for your help, but can the `disabled` change after user has submit his option

Answer (score 0):

- Select the inputs
- forEach over the inputs
- add an event listener for each *input*
- disable the checkbox inside the onClick event listener callback.

Like so:

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

function disableCheckbox() {
  this.disabled = true;
}

inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('click', disableCheckbox));
```

---

JSBIN Example:

https://jsbin.com/cicenon/edit?html,js,output

Comment: thank for your help, but can the `disabled` change after user has submit his option